# Composer Business Network Connection not working with NodeJS App

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to connect my IBM Bluemix NodeJS App with a composer-client@0.13.2 to a running Composer Business Network with runtime@0.13.2. However, I am getting the following error:

```
2017-10-29T01:55:26.36-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR (node:60) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "ibm-bc-org1". 
/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header-/home/vcap/app/node_modules/fabric-
client/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node: 
invalid ELF header
```

I manually created the `.composer-credentials/ibm-bc-org1/connection.json` file and `.composer-credentials/ibm-bc-org1` directory for key storage under my project directory. This setup works locally and I can see the result of my connection and I can get events and such on my local machine. Anyone know what the procedure is for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means you have somehow put a grpc binary (which is a dependency of composer) from your machine up onto bluemix and that binary file is not compatible with where it is trying to run.
You need to ensure you push just your application to bluemix (do not push up the node_modules directory) and get it to perform an npm install to pull down the correct dependencies and binaries (or compile the binaries) for the specific platform it will run on.

Comment: I tried to push without my `node_modules` however it still gives me the same error.

Comment: When you push do you see npm install being run ? You should check the output especially in relation to grpc. npm install must run within the environment it runs in to ensure the grpc is the correct version for the platform.

Comment: It worked when I removed `node_modules/fabric-client` from my local and pushed it. I saw it fetch and download a new grpc binary with a different installation path! Thanks!